# how to select an element in the list of elements using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0

I click on the drop down list button.Then it is coming like the mentioned picture.
 so I have to click on Item1. after that I have to select Xyz. so which way should I follow? [image]

Comment: please share your html code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways.

By using `getFirstSelectedOption()`, you can select your first element, and by using `selectByVisibleText("Xyz")` selenium will click on Xyz, but the thing is your DOM must contain select attribute for dropdown. There are many other ways to create dropdown option in HTML.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='ext-gen7']")));
dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption();
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Xyz");
```

Now, if your DOM is not using select for creating dropdown, you can also use the `.click()` method directly. Find the elements and click on that location directly using `.click()`. This will work many times.

```
List<WebElement> examples = driver.findElements(By.xpath("YOUR XPATH"));

for (WebElement option: examples) 
{ 
        if(option.getText().contains("Item2") )
         option.click();       
        else{
           syso("I do not want to click")
     }
}
```

**Make sure the above Xpath should return all your values of dropdown.**

Comment: Element should have been "select" but was "div":-Exception is coming. Is there any way to avoid this exception? because I tried with so many methods for doing this.

Comment: did you try - find the element and click it normally as same we click any button

Comment: yes.If I will write like driver.findElement(By.id(..)) then no exception is coming.But If I will use  Select class then exception is coming.It is because of element is not defined in select tag in html.It is defined in div tag.can you please suggest me how to select an element if it is defined in div tag.

Comment: what I mean to say clicking is possible but how to select ?After clicking that dropdown another drop down is coming.There I am not able to click also.If i can click there then no need of select class.

Comment: You can't use select in that case as I have mentioned in answer. For that you need to use div List<WebElements> and then click them according to need in loop ... If you can share the html then I can write the code for you

Comment: I have updated by code.. But that code will click all your value one by one.. now you need to add condition here according to your need

Comment: It is working.But after clicking that another list of item is coming.like >Item1 >item2    >item3. I want to select one value which is under Item2.

Comment: That's why I said that share your HTML code .. you need to add condition for same according to your need ... I have update my answer please have a look